# Empty value when serve the template

Tags: go, go-templates

The data structure is defined as:

```
type TopicModels struct {
    Topics string
}
```

and the viewHandler is:

```
func viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    page, _ := loadTopicModels("topics")

    templates := template.Must(template.ParseGlob("./templates/*"))
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "indexPage", page)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}
```

For the page variable, the returned value is:

```
return &TopicModels{Topics: "test"}, nil
```

Then, in html, I use {{.Topics}} to show the value inside.
However, I do not get any value, which means null.

The template is:

```
{{define "indexPage"}}
<html>
{{template "header"}}
<body onload="initialize()">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome to TDT Project</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="block-center">
        <div>
            <div class="btn-group-vertical float-left">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">{{.Topics}}</a>

                <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
            </div>
            <div id="googleMap"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="bot-block">
            Global Semantic Graph
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

Where {{header}} is another html file, which contains

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css">
```

and

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Is there anything that I need to notice when I use ExecuteTemplate()?
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: @ThunderCat The template is very simple. All other things is correct, just have null value for the {{.Topics}}.  In addition, when I put a value for page.Topics in viewHandler(), it looks like does not work at all.( page.Topics = "test2")

Comment: @ThunderCat I get the correct answer when I print before executing the template. I think I need to re-edit the question, because there might something wrong with the template.

Comment: @ThunderCat I find something that really strange. When I comment on "http.HandleFunc("/index", viewHandler)" and "http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)", the "http://localhost:8090/index" still works. And when I change the html file, the changes also show on the browser!!! I think the solution may be related to this strange problem!!!

Comment: Sounds to me like you're not actually building your source if it still works when you comment the whole thing out. Either that or you have a built copy sitting in your GOPATH somewhere. However the HTML changes because its a static file that the old code is serving. Perhaps look in your GOPATH/pkg directory for a `.a` file with your package name and delete it. Then try building again and see if that fixes it.

Comment: How are you running your Go programs? `go run file.go` on the command line? `go build && ./nameofyourbinary` on the command line? Or are you using `go install` and then running the `binaryname` from your $PATH?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Thanks. When I kill the progress of go and restart it again, I found the value is set in browser. But when I changed the code and `go run main.go`, the value in the browser is not changed. The only way to make it is killing the progress and do `go run main.go`.

Comment: @elithrar I use go `run main.go`

Comment: @Wyatt Correct - `go run` is just a shortcut for `go build && ./something.out`. It doesn't watch your file for changes; you must kill it and run it again if you make changes to your Go code.

Comment: @ThunderCat Thanks. But why I have to kill the progress and run the app, then the html page can be changed?